# Char array to integer

Tags: c, integer, arrays

I have 2 questions.

Here in the C++ reference

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char sentence []="Rudolph is 12 years old";
  char str [20];
  int i;

  sscanf (sentence,"%s %*s %d",str,&i); <---
  printf ("%s -> %d\n",str,i);

  return 0;
}
```

**Question 1. What exactly is %*s doing?**

My program I'm building a hash table.

It queries the user to either type  in

```
q- quit
i <int> - inserts integer //must be on same line
d <int> - deletes integer //must be on same line
etc....

For example:

in order to insert "35" I would have to type:

i 35
```

**Question 2. Would the C++ reference work for both 'q' and 'i 35' since 'q' has no integer with it?**

```
char choice[10];
char option;
int i;

sscanf(choice, "%c %d", &option, &i);
```

Would this work if 'q' was entered(no integer attached) as well as if "i 35" was entered (w/integer attached)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it should skip that type from the stream. So for example the input stream is:

```
"Rudolph is 12 years old"
```

The first `%s` will capture `"Rudolph"`, the `%*s` will "read but ignore" `"is"` (i.e. not store it in a variable), and then the `%d` will read and capture the `12`.

I'm not quite sure what you mean with your second question. I believe you're asking if the `"%s %*s %d"` format will work with reading `"q"` from the input. In that case, you should use a different format, like `"%s"` or `"%c"` for a single character.

In response to your updated question, you can easily try it and see. In my tests, it does work with an input of `"q"`: `sscanf` leaves the `int` alone but does read in the `"q"`.